# how to disable master branch in bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I have a bamboo plan with two branches, br1 and br2.

currently, bamboo launches automatically every time there is a commit on the master branch, branch b1 and br2.

I don't want bamboo to launch automatically when there is a commit on branch br1 and br2, but I do not want bamboo to launch automatically when there is a commit on the master branch.

How to achieve this?

(bamboo allows to disables branches, but I don't see how to disable the master branch)

ps: I am aware that bamboo is a bad choice, and we are eventually moving to jenkins. however we still need to use bamboo for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The same [question](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/144064/can-i-configure-bamboo-plan-branching-to-exclude-running-a-job-on-the-master-branch) has been asked on the Bamboo Q&A forum.

The current selected answer there is:

> Andy Davidson:
>   "Ok so the answer that i found that works (in case anyone else is interested) is to insert the regular expression ^((?!master).)*$ into the "Only Create Branches that Match" field on the branch configuration tab"

Comment: I'm going to test this since I've got the same issue.

Comment: Note that I'm using also a branch name filter to only build the release branches.  e.g. `^(?!master)integrations/release_([1-9]).*$`